# Deleting Dynamic array in java

Tags: java, dynamic-arrays

In C++, dynamically allocated array has to be deleted unless it is lost in the memory. In java, do we have to do the same, and if so. How do you do that

Comment: no, it is garbage collected.

Comment: In Java you don't have to worry about "common" memory leaks... The in-built garbage Collector will take care of it...

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647194/do-not-understand-scope-of-objects-in-java-java-newbie-confusion

Comment: @TheLostMind Java has "common" memory leaks too if you keep at least a strong reference of the array somewhere (f.e. as member in a singleton class) although you don't use it. The strong reference will prevent the array from getting eligible for garbage collection. In that case you have to null-out the reference to the array.

Comment: @RomanVottner - I take that under the "not-common" category.. By common I just mean objects (arrays) etc...

Comment: @TheLostMind I don't get the difference, TBH. Java GC takes a lot of responsibility from the developer to the JVM. Though, this does not mean that developers do not have to worry about memory at all. It is still good to know where the data is actually stored, when it may get GC and when it is not able to be GCed as an object is still holding a strong reference to the unneeded data.

Comment: @RomanVottner - What you are speaking of is a very specific case (a perfectly valid example). What I said to the OP is simple- "You dont have to worry about common Memory leak issues (in C++ he has to call free() explicitly) the GC will take care of it 'most' times".

Answer (score 2):

In the Java programming language, dynamic allocation of objects is achieved using the new operator. An object once created uses some memory and the memory remains allocated till there are references for the use of the object. When there are no references for an object, it is assumed to be no longer needed and the memory occupied by the object can be reclaimed.There is no explicit need to destroy an object as java handles the de-allocation automatically. The technique that accomplishes this is known as Garbage Collection.Programs that do not de-allocate memory can eventually crash when there is no memory left in the system to allocate. These programs are said to have memory leaks.

In Java,Garbage collection happens automatically during the lifetime of a java program, eliminating the need to de-allocate memory and avoiding memory leaks.
In C language, it is the programmer’s responsibility to de-allocate memory allocated dynamically using free() function.
Read more at http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-garbage-collection.html#wpewoJfMWffgXd8O.99

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your definition of dynamic array. Do you mean a collection of items where its length is unknown initialiazing it? If yes, you're talking about collections such as an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

You don't have to worry about the deletion of your objects. The JVM will take care of your objects when they're not used anymore or when [they're out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647194/do-not-understand-scope-of-objects-in-java-java-newbie-confusion).

The JVM analyses the execution of your code and it will invoke a special component, named [Garbage Collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), that it will clean the execution code from useless/out of scope objects.

For example, when you have this code:

```
if(condition)
{
   string myStr = "test";
   //other code here
}
```

The variable `myStr`, because it's not used anymore (it's out of scope of the `if` statement), will be marked by the JVM to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

The developer need not worry about deallocating the memory in java. The Java Garbage Collector do that for you. You can read how it works [here](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx)